# Is there an example such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ vanishes at some point but we can solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ near the point and ...?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

On p.77,

> Example 4. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by the equation $$f(x,y)=y^2-x^4.$$
> Then $(0,0)$ is a solution of the equation $f(x,y)=0$. Because $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ vanishes at $(0,0)$, we do not expect to be able to solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ near $(0,0)$. In fact, however, we can do so, and we can do so in such a way that the resulting function is differentiable. However, the solution is not unique.

[image: y^2 - x^4 == 0]

I had the following question:

> Is there an example such that $f(x,y)=0$ at some point and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ vanishes at the point but we can solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ near the point and the resulting function is differentiable and unique near the point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about
$$f(x,y)=y^3-x^9$$
around the origin? Assuming you are only interested in real solutions.

Or
$$f(x,y)=(x-y)^2?$$
A double root makes the partial derivative vanish :-)

Comment: Jyrki Lahtonen, Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x,y)=y^3-x$ around the origin would work.

Comment: mathcounterexamples.net, Thank you very much for your answer. $f(0,0)=0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0, 0)=0$ and we can solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and the resulting function is unique. But I think the resulting function is not differentiable at $x=0$.